# Microsoft Cognitive services in swift 3

Tags: swift3, alamofire, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use microsoft face recognition for my app. I have signed up for an account and started to implement into my app but cannot get any response except for `404 resource not found`. Any ideas as to where I should start with this one?

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire


class CognitiveService {

static let instance = CognitiveService()
static let apiKey = API_KEY /// set in constants file
static let apiUrl = FACE_DETECT_URL /// set in constants file


func test() {
    var header = [String : String]()
    header["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = CognitiveService.apiKey

    let url = "any web address to image here"

    let params:[String: String] = ["url": url]

    let request = Alamofire.request(CognitiveService.apiUrl, parameters: params, headers: header)

    print("\(request)")

    request.responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming FACE_DETECT_URL is set correctly, the issue is you're making a HTTP GET request (the default for Alamofire) when you wanted a POST.  So you'll want:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(CognitiveService.apiUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
```

Comment: Ok, that worked to get me connecting at least now I am getting a new error. It is BadArgument JSON Parsing error. I've looked at the documentation and to the best of my knowledge i have supplied a correct `FACE_DETECT_URL` of `let FACE_DETECT_URL = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect"` and my params are a dictionary of string:string. Any suggestions here.

Comment: just figured out had to add encoding to the request

Comment: `let request = Alamofire.request(CognitiveService.apiUrl, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)`

Comment: The answer now reflects this, in case a future viewer doesn't read the comments.  Thanks!